# Lazy load a self-referencing table

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to map a self-referencing table with NHibernate 3.2.0.4000.  However, whenever I get an instance of `DomainObject`, it eagerly loads the subsequent versions.  I'd rather not have to put an extra column my table, though that is an option.

Can I have NHiberante not eagerly load all of the subsequent versions without maintaining the relationship on both sides?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="NHibernateHierarchyTest" namespace="NHibernateHierarchyTest" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="DomainObject" table="DOMAIN_OBJECT" lazy="true" >
        <id name="DomainObjectId" column="DOMAIN_OBJECT_ID">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="Property">
            <column name="PROPERTY" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="PreviousVersion" class="DomainObject" >
            <column name="PREVIOUS_VERSION_DOMAIN_OBJECT_ID" />
        </many-to-one>
        <!--<many-to-one name="SubsequentVersion" class="DomainObject">
            <column name="SUBSEQUENT_VERSION_DOMAIN_OBJECT_ID" />
        </many-to-one>-->
        <one-to-one name="SubsequentVersion" class="DomainObject" property-ref="PreviousVersion" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `one-to-one` mapping will be always loaded eagarly with NHibernate. Not sure if this is a feature or bug, but that is how it works. If you need lazy load, use `many-to-one` or `one-to-many`. Not the best answer I know, but if you can add new column...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm a fan of the DRY principal, but the additional column is less bad that having NHibernate eagerly load dozens and dozens of objects, each with their own one-to-ones.  That's a lot of loading.  This must be the best answer because it's the only right answer, as much as I was hoping it wasn't.